# Tracking changes in MDPI journal

Tags: changes, mdpi, trackchanges

I tried to keep track of changes for a publication in the MDPI journal.
I found that it is not sufficient to just turn on track changes. When I archive the project, all the tracked changes will be gone. So, I tried also to use the following package to keep track of change

```
\usepackage[margins]{trackchanges}
```

but it doesn't work!

```
Output: This compile didn’t produce a PDF.
```

my code:

```
\documentclass[sensors,review,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{algorithmicx, algpseudocode, algorithm}

\usepackage[margins]{trackchanges}

%=================================================================
% MDPI internal commands
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
%\doinum{}
\pubyear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2020}

\Title{title}

\TitleCitation{Title}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}
Introduction of article. 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\reftitle{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
% Reference 1

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `Definitions/mdpi` would be better `mdpi` the argument is a class name, not a file path although it does appear to work that is a accident of the implemntation. but `mdpi.cls` is not in texlive, can you link to a copy?

Comment: I had the same problem, so did you solve it later?

Answer (score 0):

The [changes package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changes) worked for me really well. You first have to include the package with `\usepackage[draft]{changes}` or `\usepackage[final]{changes}`. Then you annotate the deleted, replaced and added text with `\deleted{}`, `\replaced{}`, and `\added{}` respectively.

Switching between `\usepackage[draft]{changes}` and `\usepackage[final]{changes}` gives you the draft (tracked changes) version and the final version respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach without using any extra-packages to record, track and accept changes.

Without intention to advertise tracking and accepting changes is a premium feature in Overleaf ([Track Changes in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Track_Changes_in_Overleaf)).

[image: fromOverleaf]
[image: OverleafVideo]

Though I didn't find details about its technical implementation this service seems to build on [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository), an open source version control.

Now, Git was created to allow software developers to e.g., which also happen to be Git-commands:

- *commit* intermediate versions
- *branch*, e.g. to try something out or to correct something
- *merge* branches later
- *pull* a certain version locally
- *push* own version later to the central repository
- *diff* to see differences amongst branches/versions (which gives results bearable to a software developer)
- etc.
- hence cooperate globally anytime anywhere

See e.g. this graph on the Git-idea, taken from [Git Branches: List, Create, Switch to, Merge, Push, & Delete](https://www.nobledesktop.com/learn/git/git-branches), by noble desktop, to see the similarity with Overleafs service:

[image: gitPrinciple]

Please keep in mind that both source code for software and .tex files are both plain ASCII text, meaning there's no difference from a Git-point-of-view.

While you could provide said track&accept functionality by a local Git-installation ([download e.g. from github](https://github.com/git/git)) it would be a bit tedious to do, as you:

- either run through a set of command line instructions
- or run some dedicated scripts which do so for you.

For reference, here's a typical command line view of Git in action, taken from [Git Command-Line Shortcuts](https://jonsuh.com/blog/git-command-line-shortcuts/):

[image: gitCL]

Again, without advocating, it seems that Overleaf did a nice job to hide these detailed actions (and problems sometimes arising from Git) into a Graphical User-Interface.

So depending on your preferences, ease-of-use or money, either Overleaf or Git might provide a system for you without the need of adding any other packages to track and accept changes to your code.